# Observable.empty() causes java.util.NoSuchElementException: Sequence contains no elements

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java, nosuchelementexception

I'm using Retrofit 2.0.0-beta2 with RxJava 1.0.14. I handle errors this way because I need to execute some code in doFinally:

`.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty());`

But when I get a http response with an error (401 for example) my app crashes with no my classes in the stack trace. Nothing bad happens if use `Observable.never`. Here's full stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread. Add `onError` handling.
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run (ScheduledAction.java:60)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:694)

rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: Sequence contains no elements
at rx.Observable$27.onError (Observable.java:7535)
at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError (SafeSubscriber.java:154)
at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError (SafeSubscriber.java:111)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError (OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError (OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError (OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber.pollQueue (OperatorObserveOn.java:197)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call (OperatorObserveOn.java:170)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run (ScheduledAction.java:55)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5221)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Unknown source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:899)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:694)

java.util.NoSuchElementException: Sequence contains no elements
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted (OperatorSingle.java:131)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTake$1.onCompleted (OperatorTake.java:53)
at rx.Observable$EmptyHolder$1.call (Observable.java:1077)
at rx.Observable$EmptyHolder$1.call (Observable.java:1074)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe (Observable.java:7710)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaObservable$1.onError (OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaObservable.java:76)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError (OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1$1.onError (OperatorSubscribeOn.java:71)
at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onError (SerializedObserver.java:159)
at rx.observers.SerializedSubscriber.onError (SerializedSubscriber.java:79)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTakeUntil$1.onError (OperatorTakeUntil.java:49)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.reportError (OperatorMerge.java:239)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.checkTerminate (OperatorMerge.java:774)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emitLoop (OperatorMerge.java:532)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.emit (OperatorMerge.java:521)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$InnerSubscriber.onError (OperatorMerge.java:808)
at rx.Observable$ThrowObservable$1.call (Observable.java:9600)
at rx.Observable$ThrowObservable$1.call (Observable.java:9590)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe (Observable.java:7710)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext (OperatorMerge.java:231)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMerge$MergeSubscriber.onNext (OperatorMerge.java:140)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorMap$1.onNext (OperatorMap.java:55)
at retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call (RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:113)
at retrofit.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call (RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:88)
at rx.Observable$2.call (Observable.java:162)
at rx.Observable$2.call (Observable.java:154)
at rx.Observable$2.call (Observable.java:162)
at rx.Observable$2.call (Observable.java:154)
at rx.Observable$2.call (Observable.java:162)
at rx.Observable$2.call (Observable.java:154)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe (Observable.java:7710)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSubscribeOn$1$1.call (OperatorSubscribeOn.java:62)
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run (ScheduledAction.java:55)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:422)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:237)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201 (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

Thanks,
Anton

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From the stack trace,

```
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted (OperatorSingle.java:131)
at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTake$1.onCompleted (OperatorTake.java:53)
```

This equates to `take(1).single()` which is also the `first()` convenience operator. I suspect you are using the latter, but both require at least one element.

By using `empty()`, you are creating an observable with no elements which violates the contract of the downstream operators. Either emit a default item in the `onErrorResumeNext` observable or change your downstream code to support streams with no elements.

Comment: I have the same problem. But I'm returning an empty List<MyObject> in `Observable.concat(mDatabaseObs, mRetrofitObs, mLastObs).onErrorReturn(throwable -> new ArrayList<MyObject>())
                   .first(data -> data != null && !data.isEmpty())`

To my understanding this should just emit an empty list when mRetrofitObs throws an error, first will find this empty list and move to the next one.

Comment: Old thread, but I wonder if .onErrorResumeNext(Observable.never()) would solve this issue?

Comment: What exactly does this mean: "change your downstream code to support streams with no elements"?